# Add new action in cartController.php in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, controllers

I want to add a new action in `cartController.php` (core Magento file).

How to achieve this?
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not recommended to edit core code, please follow https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/16102/extend-magento-controller-and-create-new-action

Comment: check: http://xhtmlandcsshelp.blogspot.in/2010/11/magento-overwrite-cart-controller-add.html